# Compile error with templates - no matching function for call

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, stdstring

I'm trying to convert a string to a number. For that, I found the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
T stringToNumber(const std::string &s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    T result;
    return ss >> result ? result : 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "254";
    int b = stringToNumber(a);

    std::cout << b*2 << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘stringToNumber(std::string&)’

May anyone tell me why I am getting such error and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There should be more to the error, like the fact that `T` can't be deduced.

Comment: You may need to `#include <sstream>` at the top to get std::stringstream into your scope, as well.

Comment: yep, I realized once i fixed it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
int b = stringToNumber<int>(a);
```

Because the template type `T` can not be deduced from any of the parameters (in this case `std::string`) you need to explicitly define it.

Comment: You mean *deduced*, not *derived*. Also, C++11 added `stoi`, `stol` etc. so using a `stringstream` is not necessary. And there's always `boost::lexical_cast`

Comment: @Praetorian, correct. "derived" was added to my answer by someone else.

Comment: @Paul Apologies, I was using my phone earlier and didn't both looking at the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't supplied a template argument. Note that in C++11, you can use `std::stoi`:

```
std::string a = "254";
int b = std::stoi(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution for this situation.

My solution is: Move the function implemention from .cpp file to .h file make thing ok.